# Is it feasible to store large amounts of information on DNA molecules (for years)?

Tags: solid-state-physics, information

This initially might seem like a biology based question, but I want to concentrate on the physics of DNA molecules, used purely as a manmade stable substrate for storing information.

A [2013 Ted Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4PiGWNsIEU) has stated that Watson and Cricks 1953 famous paper was transcribed onto DNA, as was the "I have a dream" MLK speech and the complete texts of Shakespeare.

So please just ignore the biology background, apart from the obvious conclusion that DNA as a storage medium has been around for 3.5 billion years (albiet with the mutations that now allow me to ask this question).

It is claimed that all the information currently stored on servers and computer hard drives (across the world) could be stored in the back of 1 (one) van/truck/lorry.

My questions are:

1. Does the high information capacity of the DNA helix exceeded any proposed holographic or similiar inorganic storage media?
2. Is there any physics based reason DNA storage could not become the norm in a relativity short time?  An example of it's possible advantage is the large amount of energy currently required to cool down server farms across the world. Unfortunately, I have no idea, as yet, of how much energy it takes to read/write to DNA or the timescale involved in performing these operations.

Comment: George Church and Sri Kosuri at the Harvard Wyss Institute stored 700 terabytes of data in one gram of DNA: http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/134672-harvard-cracks-dna-storage-crams-700-terabytes-of-data-into-a-single-gram. A Wikipedia article mentions slow speed required for data retrieval, however, as a reason this may be feasible only for archival uses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_digital_data_storage

Comment: Thanks @Ernie, it might scale up to faster speeds over time. You might be interested in seeing this alternative Microsoft way of cooling  it's present  server farms: http://www.citylab.com/tech/2016/02/microsoft-cloud-ocean-project-natick/459318/

Comment: The read/write speed of DNA sequencers and synthesizers is atrocious and so are the error rates. One could imagine workarounds around either, but then, the latest developments in 3d semiconductor memories kind of negate that by many orders of magnitude. Holographic storage was (and for a few researchers still is) the future that never was. It, too, has already been overtaken by available semiconductor technologies. Particularly Intel's Xpoint technology should revolutionize the storage industry within the next four to five years. There is _a lot_ of room at the bottom with semiconductors.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thank you.  It's the wasted energy of server farms that gets my attention, more than any particular  advantages of increased storage density. Google has more than 900,000 servers in all its data centers around the world,  uses around 260 million watts of power, enough to consistently power 200,000 average homes.

Comment: That's an important aspect, for sure, but I would posit that the energy _currently_ needed for reading the equivalent of one bit on a DNA molecule is far larger than the energy for a read operation on any semiconductor or even magnetic disc/tape device. One can also argue that maybe 90+% of the energy in current servers is wasted due to the mismatch of the problem to the hardware and software used. Server CPUs are bloated (there is zero need for FP support, L1/L2 caches are too small etc.) and sever code is byzantine, but then, none of this is physics. :-)